# Design a Multidimensional Array in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, memory-management, class-design

I want to design a C++ class for multidimensional arrays. By multidimensional I mean 1d, 2d, 3d, etc. The class supports element by element addition and scalar multiplication operators. Assume A and B are instances of the class (of the same size & dimension). I'd like to use the objects in expressions like this:

C = A * 2 + B

The thing I'm wondered about is how to manage the memory. In the above expression, A * 2 will create a temporary object of the class which is later added to B. Anyways, the temporary object is garbage after the addition is done. I wrote the following class and it works nicely but I am pretty sure it leaks the memory. Now my questions are,

1. How can I fix the memory problem? What is the best way to design the class?
2. Is that possible to allocate the required memory on the stack instead of the heap?

   ```
   class XArray
   {
       int num_dim;
       int *dims;
       int *index_helper;
       int table_size;
       double *table;


   public:
       XArray(const int n, const int *d):num_dim(n), dims(d)
       {
           int size = 1;
           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
               size *= d[i];
           }
           table_size = size;
           table = new double[size];
           index_helper = new int[n];
       };

       ~XArray()
       {
           delete[] table;
           delete[] index_helper;
       };

       int dim(int d)
       {
           return dims[d];
       }

       double& operator()(int i)
       {
           index_helper[0] = i;
           return get_helper(1, index_helper);
       }

       double& operator()(int i, int j)
       {
           index_helper[0] = i;
           index_helper[1] = j;
           return get_helper(2, index_helper);
       }

       double& operator()(int i, int j, int k)
       {
           index_helper[0] = i;
           index_helper[1] = j;
           index_helper[2] = k;
           return get_helper(3, index_helper);
       }

       XArray operator*(double m)
       {
           XArray *xa = new XArray(num_dim, dims);
           for (int i = 0; i < table_size; i++) {
               xa->table[i] = this->table[i] * m;
           }

           return *xa;
       }

       XArray operator+(const XArray &that)
       {
           if (num_dim != that.num_dim) {
               char *msg = new char[100];
               sprintf(msg, "XArray::dimensions do not match in + operation, expected %d, found %d", num_dim, that.num_dim);
               throw msg;
           }

           for (int i = 0; i < num_dim; i++) {
               if (this->dims[i] != that.dims[i]) {
                   char *msg = new char[100];
                   sprintf(msg, "XArray::dimension %d not mached, %d != %d", i, dims[i], that.dims[i]);
                   throw msg;
               }
           }       

           XArray *xa = new XArray(num_dim, dims);
           for (int i = 0; i < table_size; i++) {
               xa->table[i] = this->table[i] + that.table[i];
           }

           return *xa;
       }

   private:
       double& get_helper(int n, int *indices)
       {
           if (n != num_dim) {
               char *msg = new char[100];
               sprintf(msg, "XArray::dimensions do not match, expected %d, found %d", num_dim, n);
               throw msg;
           }

           int multiplier = 1;
           int index = 0;

           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
               if (indices[i] < 0 || indices[i] >= dims[i]) {
                   char *msg = new char[100];
                   sprintf(msg, "XArray::index %d out of range, %d not in (0, %d)", i, indices[i], dims[i]);
                   throw msg;
               }

               index += indices[i] * multiplier;
               multiplier *= dims[i];
           }

       return table[index];
   }
   ```

   };

Comment: It turns out in practice that the dimensionality of an array really belongs in the type system proper. Luckily, C++ has templates. You can make `XArray<1>` a one-dimensional array, `XArray<2>` two-dimensional, etcetera.

Comment: How about using an existing [class for multi-dimensional arrays](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html)?

Comment: @Kerrek SB -- Boost.Multi_array doesn't support the element addition and scalar multiplication operations that Mohsen appears to desire. It could be useful for the underlying implementation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should probably be in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than here. But some things on the design:

It is usually not a good idea to manage memory manually, you should prefer using existing containers instead of dynamically allocated arrays. The fact that the constructor acquires ownership of the passed in pointer is not common, and might lead to problems with user code. Currently you are disallowing some uses, like:

```
int dims[3] = { 3, 4, 5 };
XArray array( 3, dims ); // or use sizeof(dims)/sizeof(dims[0]), or other trickery
```

Which is simpler to user code than:

```
int ndims = 5;
int *dims = new int[ndims]
XArray array( ndims, dims );
```

Which also means that the user must be aware that `dims` ownership has been acquired and that they cannot `delete` the pointer.

Internally I would use `std::vector` to maintain the dynamic memory, as that will give you the proper semantics for free. As it is you need to implement copy constructor and assignment operator (or disable them) as the current code will not leak, but might try to double free some of the memory. Remember the rule of the three: if you provide any of *copy constructor*, *assignment operator* or *destructor*, you should probably provide all three.

Your `operator*` and `operator+` leak memory (the `XArray` object itself as the internal memory is actually *handled* by the absence of the copy constructor, but don't think that this is a reason not to create the copy constructor, on the contrary you *must* create it)

Throwing `char*` is allowed, but I would recommend that you don't for different reasons. The type of the exception should give information as to what happened, else your user code will have to parse the contents of the exception to determine what went wrong. Even if you decide to use a single type, note that the same rules that are used in overload resolution do not apply in exception handling, and in particular you might have problems with conversions not taking place. This is also another potential for a memory leak in your design, as in throwing a pointer to dynamically allocated memory you delegating the responsibility of releasing the memory to your users, if the user does not release the memory, or if the user does not really care about the exception and just catches everything ( `catch (...) {}` ) you will leak the errors.

It might be better if instead of `throw`ing you `assert`ed, if that is possible in your program (that is a design decision: how bad is the wrong size, something that can happen even if exceptional, or something that shouldn't happen?).

The member `index_helper` does not belong to the class, it is an implementation detail that is shared only by the different `operator()` and the `get_helper()` method, you should remove it from the class, and you can allocate it statically in each `operator()`. It is also a bit strange that you offer separate `operator()` for 1, 2 and 3 dimensions, while the code is generic to handle *any* dimensions, and also that you are actually requiring the user to *know* that out of the public interface, two of the operations are forbidden, which is not a great design either.

Comment: Thank you very much for your perfect answer. I leaned a lot. Actually, I am not a CPP programmer. A part of the problems you mentioned, like the private index_helper and preferring exceptions to assertions, comes from my background in the java culture. I laughed at the java codes written by C++ guys a lot because they try to write java just like cpp. I'm pretty sure you have a same sense when you look at my code :) Just a quick question, is there any way to write a typesafe vararg function in C++? I don't like to loose the type safety when I write a general code.

Comment: Generic code is usually handled through templates (that is one of the features I miss the most in Java), that are fully typesafe. Contrary to generics in Java where the *generic* type is type-erased, in C++ templates generate different classes/functions for each instantiation. If you are referring to the `operator()` in your code, that is one of the most complex things to do as of now. If you have a C++ compiler with variadic template support, then it is much simpler, but currently that is hard to do (i.e. the problem is that the number of arguments is not fixed).

Comment: If you want to create this type of generic N dimension array, I would consider using N as a template argument, that will create different classes for each instantiation, and then you could use the preprocessor to generate the N argument `operator()`, that is not nice, and is quite hard to make it readable, but it can be done. While creating an array that is generic in the type of the contained element is simple, creating an array that is generic on the number of dimensions and doing so with a clean interface is not a simple task.

Comment: It looks like a disaster to me. I prefer to use my dummy approach :) By the way, I changed the class following your guidelines. It uses vectors and asserts now. Much cleaner, and "seemingly" no memory leak. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I miss copy constructors and assignment operators. You will need these to make copies of the internal buffers and not just copy the pointers or otherwise you will end up freeing the same memory twice.

If you are going to support c++0x you also might want to implement the move semantics for optimal performance.

Throwing dynamically allocated objects like you are doing is a very bad idea.

In your operator* you should create the object on the heap:

```
XArray operator*(double m)
{
    XArray xa(num_dim, dims);
    for (int i = 0; i < table_size; i++) {
        xa->table[i] = this->table[i] * m;
    }

    return xa;
}
```

However as long as you don't write your (move) copy constructors this will crash. Because the return statement will make a copy that refers to the same internal data as xa. xa will be destroyed and it's destructor will destroy it's internal data. So the temp object that is being returned points internally to destroyed data.

**edit:**

Link to info about [Move semantics or rvalue references](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html)

Comment: Is there any way to allocate the internal fields (like table) on the stack? Actually, the objects created from XArray are not very large but I am going to use millions of instances, Like evaluating some complicated expressions millions of times. So, I think it would be more efficient if I could allocate them on the stack.

Comment: @Mohsen, allocation on the stack is only possible if the size is known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest following to avoid memory leaks:

1. Make **copy constructor** and `operator = ()` `private` and unimplemented to avoid `table` and `index_helper` getting overwritten (and cause memory leak accidently). If you wish you to use them, then **make sure**, you do `delete[] table` and `delete[] index_helper;` before re-assignment to avoid leak.
2. For error messages use `std::string`
   instead of `char *msg = new
   char[100];`. It's more cleaner and
   maintainable.
3. Don't use `XArray *xa = new
   XArray(num_dim, dims);`; instead
   simply declare it as `XArray xa;`.
   It will be on stack and wound up
   automatically (if you have c++0x support then you can opt for perfect forwarding to eliminate unnecessary copies)

Now with regards to your remaining `class` design, the answer will be very subjective and need detail code analysis. So, I will leave it up to you to decide.

Comment: Question about part 3: If I use "XArray xa;" the object is constructed in the stack but the internal tables are on heap. right? Is the memory for the internal storage (like the field table) deleted automatically by calling the destructor?

Comment: @Mohsen, yes `XArray` is on stack, and when it goes out of scope, its destructor `~XArray()` is called, where you are deleting the heap memory. So you need not worry about that part.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your first proposal. If I make the copy constructor private, how can I have an assignment like A = B? What happens if I write my own copy constructor and copy the internal fields?

Comment: @Mohsen, Since, I din't see them in your code, I assumed you are not intending to use them. See the edited part now.